# How to enable or modify security configuration for jhipster with thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf, jhipster

I want to use thymeleaf instead of angular JS. I can use templates with out security and i can add httpsecurity for that URL, My question is that how to authorize the URL? currently I am using JWT token mechanism.

Thanks

Comment: Which versions? Which url do you use to access your templates? Have you configured some additional AntMatchers in SecurityConfiguration#configure ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Jhipster version is 5.1.0,  template url is "http://localhost:8080/main/quote" . And added in AntMatchers ( .antMatchers("/main/**").authenticated()). Without addiing AntMatchers i can access template.

Comment: With antMatchers, what is the error?

Comment: I got this error

{
"type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
"title": "Unauthorized",
"status": 401,
"detail": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
"path": "/main/admin/index.html",
"message": "error.http.401"
}

Comment: I tried to include  this in Jhipster , if its security okay, i can go further.

https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafsandbox-springsecurity-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 401 error is expected, it means you did not provide a valid token.

When using Thymeleaf templates, JWT is not the best choice because it means you will have to write some javascript to handle it as a HTTP header which seems to goes against what you wanted to achieve (not using angular).

I'd recommend that you use cookies and so select session auth type.

Please note that you could also modify JHipster JWT code so that it uses a cookie rather than a HTTP header but this is more work than simply using session auth type?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I got your point. I looked possibilities for JWT to using mobile app and session with JWT for thymeleaf. My Idea is that put bearer token in session, if token missing in header,  try to get in session. I am not sure that it will work. But I hope It will require lot of changes.  Thanks a lot for answering my question.